# Problemas en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

gracias por leer, espero que puedan ayudarme con el siguiente problema.

Nunca había tenido este problema, pero comenzó hace pocos días, el error parece que esta en colors.xml, en varios de los proyectos que he creado aparece este error, la dirección de ese proyecto no debería estar ahí, ese proyecto ya lo borre, pero no se que pasa, actualice varias cosas en android studio pero no paso nada, intente el clean/ rebuild project y el Invalidate Caches/ Restart, pero nada paso, no se que puede tener, alguien aquí podría orientarme o conoce alguna forma de resolver este error.

Agradezco que se hayan tomado el tiempo de leer.

A continuación dejo algunas capturas de mi problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El proyecto de las imágenes es el que esta eliminado pero aun aparece? O solo es la dirección?

Comment: El error en consola dice que abriste etiquetas en ```colors.xml``` y nunca las cerraste. Y según las imágenes esta en lo correcto. Que pasa si cierras las etiquetas? El error en ```styles.xml``` debería solucionarse al solucionar ```colors.xml```.

Comment: @Alex, solo aparece la dirección, porque ese proyecyo ya lo borre, lo elimine de la papelera, y desconecte la usb en donde se encontraba, pero no se porque aun aparece esa dirección, recuerdo que anteriormente también había intentado cerrar las etiquetas, pero no funciono.

Comment: Entonces el código que te muestra es el de otro proyecto?

Comment: @Alex, así es, es otro proyecto completamente diferente, que esta ubicado en otra usb con un nombre completamente diferente, pero por alguna razón aparece otra dirección, intente crear otros proyectos, pero tenían el mismo problema y otros proyectos pasado, comenzaban a tener errores sin motivo aparente.

Comment: Ya intentaste cerrar las etiquetas en ```colors.xml```? Esos proyectos con los que has tenido problemas eran recién creados? Al crear un nuevo proyecto ya salen así?

Comment: @Alex, intente cerrar las etiquetas en otros proyectos, pero en este no, los otros proyectos con los que tuve problemas eran recién creados, pero también había otros que habían sido creados anteriormente y también presentaban problemas, al crear un proyecto nuevo ya salen estos problemas, ya intenta hasta reiniciar mi computadora, actualice varias cosas en android studio, pero nada parece funcionar.

Comment: Que me dices de las plantillas que usa tu android studio para generar los proyectos? Están correctas?

Comment: @Alex, si te refieres al Layout, pues parece que esta bien, pero no puedo visualizar el diseño en el editor, y siempre uso un empty activity para trabajar.